# Как заменить "точка пробел точка" на просто точку через регулярные выражения

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Задача чтобы строка:

```
. . . Hello . . . . . . world . . .
```

стала:

```
. Hello . world .
```

заменить "точка пробел точка" на просто точку

пробовал так:

```
/(\.\s\.)+/i
```

Answer (score 3):

Мы можем обозначить замену как любую точку, которая, в свою очередь, сопровождается пробелом и другой точкой, причем все количество происходит один или несколько раз. То есть мы можем найти следующий шаблон, а затем заменить его только одной точкой:

```
\.( \.)+
```

Пример кода:

```js
const input = '. . . Hello . . . . . . world . . .'

console.log(
  input.replace(/\.( \.)+/g, '.')
)
```

Также можно использовать

```
/\.(?: \.)+/
```

который просто говорит движку регулярных выражений не записывать то, что находится внутри `()`. Таким образом, это может сделать замену немного более эффективной, вы можете использовать этот вариант, если хотите.

Comment: Супер!!! Большое спасибо!

Comment: @user1410154 Пожалуйста, отметьте решение как верное (щелкните галочку слева от ответа).